# Firebird UDF creation failure

Tags: sql, firebird, user-defined-functions

I have a firebird database that I need to recreate. It contains an external UDF function. I made an SQL dump of the DB structure using IB Expert:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION LPAD
    CSTRING(255),
    INTEGER,
    CSTRING(1)
RETURNS CSTRING(255) FREE_IT
ENTRY_POINT 'IB_UDF_lpad' MODULE_NAME 'ib_udf'
```

However, I get an error when I run the query:

> Invalid token.
>   Dynamic SQL Error.
>   SQL error code = -104.
>   Token unknown - line 1, column 27.
>   'LPAD'.

I'm using Firebird 2.1.1 on Windows. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION "LPAD"
    CSTRING(255),
    INTEGER,
    CSTRING(1)
RETURNS CSTRING(255) FREE_IT
ENTRY_POINT 'IB_UDF_lpad' MODULE_NAME 'ib_udf'
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked - I tried escaping with single quotes, but it did not. I wonder why this would make any difference, and why does IB Expert export it incorrectly...

Comment: Firebird 2.1 added an internal implementation of LPAD. Because LPAD is now a keyword, it is not supported unescaped in this context. See http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-lpad.html